# How to secure/authenticate communication between Spring Boot Application and Spring Boot Microservice?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

I've tried to find a kind of a standard solution for the following situation but haven't found anything but extrem complex implementations.

I have a Spring Boot main application which works kind of a monolith, including MVC and Security. I now want to outsource a specific service which will only be called from the main application.

Is there a simple solution to have these two applications (main and microservice) communicating sercurely (token?) without implementing complex architecture like `API Gateway + Service Registry +++`?

Can anybody provide links or information to this topic where things kept simple? In the end, all I want to do is making a secure/authenticated API call to the microservice, although the microservice should not be accessible from public.

Many thanks for any information